# How can I write a method that returns the value of a of xaml toggle switch?

Tags: c#, xaml, toggle

I have two xaml toggles in separate files that I want to update simultaneously (if one is switched on the other should be too (and vice versa). My first switch in xaml is:

```
<Switch Grid.Column="1" x:Name="toggleSwitch1" IsToggled="true" Toggled="OnToggled"/>
```

Using C# how can I return a boolean value of this switch so that I can update another switch simultaneously? Then once retrieving the value, how can I update the xaml of the toggle status for the other switch?

Comment: Imho, you shouldn't return any values of `IsToggled` property. Instead of it, you should bind both `Switch` controls to mutual `bool` property. Than changing that property value will affect both `Switch` controls. Also toggling one `Switch` will toggle another and vice versa.

Comment: That sounds exactly like what I need. I've looked into it more but do you have any code or documentation you could point me to?

Comment: Added example, please try yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Switch` control means, as I can understand, that you using UWP, but I'm not sure.

Anyway, the idea is to **bind** both controls `IsToggled` properties to same property of some **ViewModel**:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace MyWPFApp
{
    public class ControlsViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private bool switchToggled;
        public bool SwitchToggled
        {
            get => switchToggled;
            set
            {
                switchToggled = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SwitchToggled));
            }
        }

        public ControlsViewModel() { }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "") => 
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Then in **XAML** of both `Window`s set bindings to `Switch` control (in my example - `CheckBox` control):

```
<!-- Window 1 -->
<Window x:Class="MyWPFApp.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyWPFApp"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Window 1" Height="100" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <CheckBox Content="Window1 CheckBox"
                  IsChecked="{Binding SwitchToggled}"/>
                  <!-- Replace IsChecked to IsToggled property -->
    </Grid>
</Window>

<!-- Window 2 -->
<Window x:Class="MyWPFApp.Window2"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyWPFApp"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Window 2" Height="100" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <CheckBox Content="Window2 CheckBox" 
                  IsChecked="{Binding SwitchToggled}"/>
                  <!-- Replace IsChecked to IsToggled property -->
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Code-behind** of both `Window`s in example is same:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace MyWPFApp
{
    public partial class Window1 : Window // or public partial class Window2
    {
        public Window1(ControlsViewModel cvm) // or public Window2
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = cvm;
        }
    }
}
```

And when calling that example `Window`s to **show** from Main one, you creating `ControlsViewModel` instance and pass it to both:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace MyWPFApp
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var cvm = new ControlsViewModel();

            new Window1(cvm).Show();
            new Window2(cvm).Show();
        }
    }
}
```

So checking/unchecking (toggle/untoggle) one of them will affect another and vice versa. Also, you can change `SwitchToggled` from code somewhere, which would affect both controls too.

[image]

Please note, that this is just example to try explain the idea. More MVVM pattern explanations and examples you can find at [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern).

Comment: Thanks for this answer but I believe since I am working with xamarin android, the Window(s) were giving me errors. I've reposted my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70027409/how-to-bind-two-switch-controls-in-separate-classes-to-the-same-bool-property) and would really appreciate if you could take a look at what I have!

Comment: @JM Wesierski, I've added comment there. Re-read again my answer, especially part of MainWindow. As you see, there I create only 1 instance of ViewModel and pass this instance as same for each child windows. I do not create separate instances in each child window, just assign passed one from MainWindow as DataContext.